# How to change the height of SWT ToolBar?

Tags: windows, height, size, swt, toolbar

Im using SWT on windows and no matter what I do the ToolBar height is 22px. In my toolbar I have two Text(fields). When the user increases the overall OS font size to eg. 125% or 150% all other widgets are increased in size to fit the increased fontsize. However the toolbar stays at 22px making text in the toolbar overflow and looking less good. I have tried to set the layout data on the tool bar, but it does not help. Any??

Comment: This is probably platform dependent so which platform are you using? On my Mac it works fine.

Comment: I am on the Windows 8 platform, maby it's a platform issue?

Comment: Ok, i found the solution, someone else mentioned it here on Stack. After the first image is added to the toolbar all other images are scaled to that size. And if not an image, it is scaled to the height of the first image. But it still does not solve the problem, when the user increases the oferall OS font and gui scaling. Images are not scaled accordingly. But they can be scaled at runtime and then add to the toolbar.